# django file displays the contents of a database outside the dropdown menu

Tags: python, html, css, django

I have a delete employee page in my Django project where I get all the names of the employees in the dropdown menu from the database. the main issue is when I run the code the content which is supposed to be shown inside the dropdown menu is shown ouside. the code is as below:

```
''' {% extends 'app/base.html' %}
{% block para %}
<title>delete employee</title>

<body style="background-color:powderblue;"></body>
<style type="text/css">
    label{
        width: 200px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 4px;
        text-align: left;
        font-weight:bold;
    }
    input{
        width: 200px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 4px;
        text-align: left;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
    select{
        width: 200px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 4px;
        text-align: left;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }
    form{
        border-radius: 10px;
        background: rgb(155, 206, 219) ;
        color: white;
        width: 450px;
        padding: 4px;
        margin:auto;
    }
    
    
    
</style>
    <form action="" >
        
        <h3 class="text-center text-uppercase"style="color:black; font-weight:bold">delete-employee</h3>
        {% csrf_token %}
        
           
        <label for="" class="text-uppercase">select:</label> 
        {% for emp in emps  %}
        <option value="ceo" class="text-uppercase">{{emp.name}}</option>
        {% endfor %}
        <select name="designation" id="designation">
        <option value="associates" selected class="text-uppercase">name</option>        
        </select><br><br>
        
        <div class="container">
        <input type="submit" value="submit" class="text-uppercase text-center">
</div>

    </form>
</div>
{% endblock para %}'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Your options should be inside the select tag, like this:

```
<select name="designation" id="designation">
  {% for emp in emps  %}
    <option value="ceo" class="text-uppercase">{{emp.name}}</option>
  {% endfor %}       
</select>
```

Comment: now the options don't come inside the selection box.